# Angular 9 : Children routing inside lazy loaded component not working

Tags: javascript, angular

I have app component in which i lazy load create-new-module with component profilecomponent. now in profile component i hit router.navigate and trying to load another children detail in place of profile but its not working also no error in console.

please help

```js
// App component route

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'create-new-emp',
    loadChildren: () => import('./create-new-emp/create-new-emp.module').then(c => c.CreateNewEmpModule),
  },
  { path: '',  redirectTo: 'create-new-emp', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: '**',  redirectTo: 'create-new-emp'}
];


// Emp Module Route

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ContainerComponent,
  children: [
    { path: '', component: ProfileComponent, outlet: 'form'},
    { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, outlet: 'form'},
    { path: 'detail', component: DetailComponent, outlet: 'form' }] }
];

// Trying to hit below link but not working

this.router.navigate(['detail'])
```

```html
<app-component>
<router-outlet>
<container-component>
<profile-component></profile-component>
</container-component>
</router-outlet>
</app-component>
```

Comment: I suggest you create a project on stackblitz.com recreating your scenario and that way we can help you here much better.

Answer (score 0):

Complicated with only these information to help. But  is the way angular navigates amount components/pages. I think what you are trying to do is navigate between components (according your router.ts). If you want to navigate, you only need router-outlet in your html code and not use component tag in the HTML code.

Change this:

```
<app-component>
<router-outlet>
<container-component>
<profile-component></profile-component>
</container-component>
</router-outlet>
</app-component>
```

To this:

```
<app-component>
<router-outlet>
</router-outlet>
</app-component>
```

Then, into ContainerComponent.html you need to repeat to navigate to details o profile because these are child routes.

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

That will give you more information about what you need.

Comment: there is nothing inside <router-outlet> .... i just gave idea about hoe my DOM structure is

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to say with this info, but may... you should define de router outlet name

```
<router-outlet  name="form"></router-outlet>
```

Hope it's help.